# what could be the cause of this error in python vs code?

Tags: python

```
enter code here
i = 0
sums = []
while i <= 1000:
    if i%3==0 or i%5==0:
        sums.append(i)
    i=i+1
for i in sums:
    total = sums[i] + sums[i+1]
print(total)
```

The problem was:
If we list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or 5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9. The sum of these multiples is 23.

Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000.
After i run the above code it brings out this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "c:\Users\user\Desktop\Python projects\Multiples of 3 or 5.py", 
line 8, in <module>
   total = sums[i] + sums[i+1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Did you look at the values in `sums`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values inside your list can only be used as indices if they are in fact within the range of your list.

But as you append `i` to `sums` like this:

```py
while i <= 1000:
    if i%3==0 or i%5==0:
        sums.append(i)
    i=i+1
```

Thus making your last element in `sums[-1] = 1000` but `sums` is of length `468`. So the highest index you could use is 467, as lists count beginning with `0` up to `len(nums)-1`.
That is why you get the `IndexError: list index out of range` message.

To get the total of all values, you can either use a loop iterating over all elements in `sums` or use the built-in `sum` function:

```py
total = 0
for num in sums:
    total += num
print(total)
```

Or calling `sum` with `nums`:

```py
print(sum(nums))
```

Comment: please expound on sums is of length 468?

Comment: You don't have all 1000 numbers in sums because you filter all values divisble by 3 and 5. That's why `sums` has only 468 numbers stored

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in sums:
    total = sums[i] + sums[i+1]
```

imagine that sums array have 5 elements.
and values like [3,5,7,10,15]
and when you looped like above, it assigns values in order 3,5,7,10,15.
So as we do not have seventh elementh in the list it gives up an error.
However there is a easier way to do this

```
print(sum(sums))
```